# is enable Google reCAPTCHA for e-commerce good or not?

Tags: user-expectation, users, security, google

I am opening anew e-commerce website, my question is is enable Google reCAPTCHA user friendly or not?
actually,I am planing to disable reCAPTCH for users for the first three months that will make login and create account more easily,what did you think?

Comment: Related but much older post: [Accessibility and CAPTCHAs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/26230/91974).

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Go for Invisible captcha. It will not hamper the registration experience on your website for genuine users.

**Long Answer:**
CAPTCHA helps in identifying between real users and automated users/BOTs. It will avoid SPAM registration on your website.
Is that a common occurrence that you have observed on your website?
If yes, then review sections, the comment sections on your e-commerce website can be targeted for spam.
I personally believe that Fake reviews, irrelevant comments are bad user experiences.
So it's better to guard your website with CAPTCHA so that your genuine users do not suffer from Spam.

The downside to having a CAPTCHA would mean that potential users would have to take efforts while registering to your website to prove that they are not a BOT. So a win-win scenario for both, registering users and you as a website owner would be to opt for invisible or silent CAPTCHA.

You can get more information on it here: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html?ref=producthunt

Comment: +1 for invisible capcha. Some sites also display the captcha if they connect through VPN or from a suspected IP range.

Adding a non professional personal opinion: I dislike captcha's with a passion. If a captcha makes me loose even one second saying not correct input, I immediately bounce from the page. It's their loss. I don't have time and patience to decipher low pixel images and text.